# Necesito ayuda con un trigger en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hola como están quisiera ver si alguien me puede ayudar con un trigger en postgres , lo que pasa es que yo se como hacerlo en sql server y pensé que era algo similar pero creo que no lo es , dejo mi consulta que me arroja errores de que esta mal escrita.

Ya probé los select y los insert y si funcionan bien lo único que no estoy seguro es que si en postgres utilizo el inserted al momento del trigger y también cual es la estructura que tendría con este ejemplo, porfa si alguien me ayudara estaría super agradecido.

```
CREATE  TRIGGER reten_account AFTER insert ON retenciones_ventas  
    [
         BEGIN

          insert into account_move(name ,date , ref ,state, 
          type,to_check,journal_id,company_id,partner_id,

          commercial_partner_id,amount_total,auto_post,invoice_date,invoice_partner_display_name,
          create_uid,create_date,write_date,write_uid,extract_state,
          numero_documento,"type_documentId",currency_id)
           (select  inserted."nameSeq",CURRENT_DATE,'','posted', 
           'in_invoice','false',inserted.journal_id,account_move.company_id
         ,inserted.partner_id,inserted.partner_id,'0.00','false',
          inserted.date_ret,account_move.invoice_partner_display_name,
          inserted.create_uid,inserted.create_date,inserted.write_date,
           inserted.write_uid,account_move.extract_state
          ,inserted.numero_retencion,inserted."type_documentId",account_move.currency_id
         from  inserted
           inner join account_move on account_move.id = inserted.invoice_id)

    insert into 
    account_move_line(move_id,move_name,date,journal_id,company_id,company_currency_id,
    account_id,account_internal_type,
    name,quantity,price_unit,debit,credit,balance,price_total,partner_id,create_date,create_uid,
    write_uid,write_date)
    (select lines.customerorder_id,inserted."nameSeq",CURRENT_DATE,
    inserted.journal_id,account_move.company_id,
    account_move.currency_id,lines.account_id,'other',inserted."nameSeq",'1',0- 
   (lines.total*-1),'0',lines.total *-1,0-(lines.total*-1),0- 
   (lines.total*-1),account_move.partner_id,inserted.create_date,inserted.create_uid,
   inserted.write_uid,inserted.write_date

    from  inserted
    inner join retenciones_ventas_retenciones_ventas_lines as lines on lines.customerorder_id = 
    inserted.id
    inner join account_move on account_move.id = inserted.invoice_id)

    insert into 
    account_move_line(move_id,move_name,date,journal_id,company_id,company_currency_id,
    account_id,account_internal_type,
    name,quantity,price_unit,debit,credit,balance,price_total,partner_id,create_date,create_uid,
    write_uid,write_date)
   (select lines.customerorder_id,inserted."nameSeq",CURRENT_DATE,inserted.journal_id,
   account_move.company_id,
   account_move.currency_id,lines.account_id,'other',inserted."nameSeq",'1', 
   (lines.total*-1)-0,lines.total *-1,'0'
   ,(lines.total*-1)-0,(lines.total*-1)-0,account_move.partner_id,inserted.create_date,
   'inserted.create_uid,
    inserted.write_uid,inserted.write_date

    from  inserted
    inner join retenciones_ventas_retenciones_ventas_lines as lines on lines.customerorder_id = 
    inserted.id
    inner join account_move on account_move.id = inserted.invoice_id)

    update account_move set amount_total = (select sum(lines.total)*-1
    from  inserted
    inner join retenciones_ventas_retenciones_ventas_lines as lines on lines.customerorder_id = 
    inserted.id
    inner join account_move on account_move.id = inserted.invoice_id) where id =(select 
    invoice_id
    from  inserted
    inner join retenciones_ventas_retenciones_ventas_lines as lines on lines.customerorder_id = 
    inserted.id
    inner join account_move on account_move.id = inserted.invoice_id)



    END;

];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear TRIGGER en postgres debes hacerlo en dos pasos:

> - primer creas una función
> - y luego a esa función la llamas con la    creación de tu trigger

seria mas o menos así:

> **Nota:** EL uso de: " **DELIMITER//** "  mayormente se ocupa si estas utilizando
>   **HeidiSQL**.

```
DELIMITER // 
create function miTriggerFuncion() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    insert into mi_tabla_2(nombre,voto,descripcion) values(OLD.nombre,OLD.voto,OLD.descripcion);/*aquí colocas lo que desea que realice tu trigger antes de de actualizar la tabla: "mi_tabla"*/
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

> Luego: Creas el trigger y invocas al método: "miTriggerFuncion()"

```
CREATE TRIGGER MI_TRIGGER BEFORE UPDATE ON mi_tabla /* El BEFORE te indica que el trigger actuara antes de que se actualice la tabla de nombre: mi_tabla */
FOR EACH ROW  /*para cada fila de la tabla*/
EXECUTE PROCEDURE miTriggerFuncion();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda Santiago , y  otra consulta si necesito hacer un select referenciandome a la tabla en esta función , por ejemplo en sql ponia inserted en vez de la tabla para que le diga a mi consulta que coja los campos que se ingresan en ese momento , en este caso con esta función como aria ese select (select * from inserted) , como seria en postrgres

Comment: Espero haberte entendido. Por ejemplo: si deseas insertar datos en la tabla "mi_tabla" antes de que se inserten,y deseas sumarle y 2 a los datos(en este caso a la columna: numero), seria de esta forma: INSERT INTO mi_tabla(numero)VALUES(8543);  en mi función: miTriggerFuncion()  yo obtengo el valor :"8543" de esta forma:

Comment: NEW.numero y una ves con ese valor yo puedo trabajarlo a mi gusto, por ejemplo: NEW.numero:= (NEW.numero + 100);//le sumo 100 antes de insertarlo en la tabla, Luego retorno ese valor con: "RETURN NEW;"  :::::: NEW lo utilizas cuando quieres obtener los valores de una inserción y OLD cuando estas actualizando o eliminando una fila de una tabla. Por cierto si te sirvió no olvides calificar la respuesta,Saludos